# Use string from one column of dataframe to reference value in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation

trying to use values from a column in the dataframe (placeholder) to reference a specific column in the same dataframe... was wondering if this is even possible. Example input and output below:

Input:

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | placeholder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9234 | 923 | 12 | 942 | 2 |
| 203841 | 1230 | 438 | 1029 | 1 |
| 94532 | 4380 | 312 | 349 | 3 |

Output:

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | placeholder | final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9234 | 923 | 12 | 942 | 2 | 12_ID |
| 203841 | 1230 | 438 | 1029 | 1 | 1230_ID |
| 94532 | 4380 | 312 | 349 | 3 | 349_ID |

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["final"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x[str(x["placeholder"])]) + "_ID", axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       ID     1    2     3  placeholder    final
0    9234   923   12   942            2    12_ID
1  203841  1230  438  1029            1  1230_ID
2   94532  4380  312   349            3   349_ID
```

---

If the columns are of type integer, remove the inner `str()`:

```py
df["final"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x[x["placeholder"]]) + "_ID", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` you can achieve your output with:

```py
df['final'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x[x['placeholder'].astype(str)]) + '_ID', axis = 1)
```

To explain this rather convoluted line, we can look it bit for bit:

```py
df.apply(..., axis = 1)
```

applies a function to each row (axis = 1) of the dataframe. The function is defined as

```py
lambda x: str(x[x['placeholder'].astype(str)]) + '_ID'
```

So we take a row `x` and then we get the value from the placeholder column and convert it to a string so we can use it as a row name:

```py
x['placeholder'].astype(str)
```

When the placeholder only contains integers, you can leave out the `astype(str)` as integers are implicitly converted to strings.

We then get the value from that column and convert it to string:

```py
str(x[...])
```

and concatenate it with the string '_ID' via the `+`-operator. And this value is then assigned to the new column `placeholder`.